# What is the easiest way to install new theme on 12.04

Tags: themes

I want new look and feel on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. What kind of look do you want. What DE are you using. Please edit your question and add details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will want to download a theme that you like. Just google for Ubuntu Themes and find one to your liking. (Ensure that it is both gtk-2.0- and gtk-3.0-compliant. Mostly, the author will make that clear. If not, after extracting the files as described below, you will have to check that the theme has folders for both gtk-2.0 and gtk-3.0.)

Extract the theme because most themes come as compressed files.

Then open your home folder and create a new folder titled `.themes`. Then move your downloaded and uncompressed theme into that folder.

When you've done all that you will need to install an advanced edit tool such as **Ubuntu Tweak**. It is installable from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Once installed, run the program and navigate to the "themes" tab and select the appropriate theme. 
Enjoy.

If you want to change your Icon theme you must download a new Icon Theme then create a `.icons` folder within your home folder. Then place the new Icon theme folder inside the `.icons` folder and you can change that in Ubuntu Tweak as well, under the Themes tab.

Remember that putting a `.` in front of a folder will make it hidden and you will need to press `Ctrl`+`H` to show hidden folders.

You may also want to make a few logical links so that programs running system-wide will pick up your theme and icons:

`sudo ln -s ~/.themes /root/.themes`

`sudo ln -s ~/.icons /root/.icons`

`sudo ln -s /home/<username>/.gtkrc-2.0 /root/.gtkrc-2.0`

These steps are based on advice [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2044806).

[image]